# Why am I not able to see my new image sizes in gutenberg image size list

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I have seen several similar questions, but none of them seem to resolve my issue.

I have customised the default thumbnail size and tried to set some custom image sizes, but they are not showing in the Gutenberg image size options - even after clearing, re-generating and re-adding images.

The thumbnail size has updated correctly though.

Below is the code used in my function.php

```
function set_custom_image_sizes() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 600, 330, true ); 

    if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
       add_image_size('hero', 1680, 837, true);
       add_image_size('person', 800, 800, true);
    }
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'set_custom_image_sizes' );

function create_custom_image_sizes($sizes){
   return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'hero' =>  __('Hero Image'),
        'person' =>  __('Person Image') 
    ));
}

add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'create_custom_image_sizes');
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this case is to realise that images in the media library also need to be regenerated even if they have not been added to a page.  To prevent the need for re-uploading all images I use a plugin called "Regenerate Thumbnails" to update all the images in the library.

Once installed the regenerate option is available in the "Tools" menu